# What is the difference between 大学的二年级学生 and 大学二年级的学生?

Tags: grammar, word

My mom says 大学二年级的学生 is correct, but I don't understand how the other one is wrong. I believe both convey the same meaning. Is one wrong because of syntax?

Comment: I would simply say 大二学生 though. Use one of 初/高/大/研 plus one of 一/二/三/四...

Answer (score 2):

The 的 in the two sentences have different functions

- [大学的] + [二年级学生] --> [of the university] + [the second-year students] = "**the second-year students** of the university" (的 here is a possessive marker that indicates the university possess the second-year students)
- [大学二年级的] + [学生]--> [of the second-year class in the university] + [students] = "**the students** of the second-year class in the university" (的 here is an adjective marker that marks 'the second-year class' as an adjectival phrase that describes the students. It can be reduced to '大学二年级学生' because unlike the possessive 的, the adjectival 的 is often omitted

Example sentence:

我們大学的二年级学生有一半是外國人 (Half of the second-year students in our university are foreigners)

小張是一名大学二年级(的)学生 (Xiao Zhang is a second-year university student)